# Outlook screws up contacts added through EWS, unable to send emails as a result

Tags: exchangewebservices, outlook-2010, ews-managed-api

Ok so that title is not the most informative, but I'm having a hard time describing whats going on.

**The Context:**
I have a C# application that manages a bunch of contacts. Using the Outlook/exchange web service (EWS) managed API I am able to create an exchange contact with the email addresses and phone numbers and all that.

This is as a replacement of a service based Active-Directory based person list (that was then linked to in outlook) also developed by us.

**The Problem:**
After removing the old active directory list this started happening.
Whenever you select a contact from my new (ews based) list (in a to: field in ta new email) it would look liked it started to auto resolve. Then it displays the message that the mail cannot be sent because the email doenst exist anymore or is not valid.

If you check the autocomplete dropdown for that contact it now displays something like this: peter keutels <8b620d77d1df4bf0b7aad23f4632a503-peterkeutels@email.adres>
and in the NDA it lists the recipient as Exchange+20Administrative+20Group+20+28FYDIBOHF23SPDLT+29_cn=Recipients_cn=8b620d77d1df4bf0b7aad23f4632a503-Peter+20Keutels@COMPANY.OFFICE
instead of just peterkeutels@email.adress

We tried clearing autocomplete, disabling auto-resolve. recreating outlook accounts...

I am totaly lost with this. I feel like this might just be an outlook problem. And in that case I probably should post this in another website. But I created the problem by using EWS. I hope I can fix it with EWS as well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After removing the old active directory list this started happening.

The first thing I would check is the contacts themselves if you look at the contacts with a MAPI editor like OutlookSpy of MFCMapi and take a look at the EmailAddress properties for the Contact you may find these Contacts have the Ex address of the List your removed. (In that case you need to fix the contacts).

> We tried clearing autocomplete

What method did you use and what version of Outlook are you using ? on later versions of Outlook this gets stored as an FAI item in the Mailbox so you might want delete that Item eg http://www.msoutlook.info/question/backup-and-restore-autocomplete

(There also the suggested contacts folder and OWA also has a seperate AutoComplete)

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Hey Glen Using OutlookSpy (nice tip) I figured that the link to the Active directory was stored under email1. While when normally viewing the contact in outlook it would list its correct email address. After fixing this everything seems to work correctly. Ow and whiping of autocomplete was done via outlook>options>email>clear autocomplete list. But thanx for the help!